# Change the background color into three areas when we have MANY plots ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which produces the plot below:

```
ggplot(data = factor_output, aes(y=F.Difference, x=reorder(Action.Title, F.Difference), fill=Efficacy.Median)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Factor1, colour="DarkRed"), size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Factor2, colour="DarkBlue"), size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Factor 1", "Factor 2"), values = c("DarkRed", "DarkBlue")) +
  labs(colour="Coefficient Value") +
  annotate("rect", ymin = c(0.3, -0.3, -0.3), ymax = c(Inf, -Inf, 0.3),
           xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
           alpha = 0.1, fill = c("green", "green", "orange")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title= element_text(size = 15),
        legend.text= element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = c(0, 1),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        plot.title = element_text(colour = "DarkRed", size = 22, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

I know from other threads on stackoverflow that I need to start with empty `ggplot()` and then add `annotate`. I tried to do that and state the `data` and `aes` for each plot, but I got a lot of error messages.

Could you please let me know how I can amend the code above to send the three background areas to the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to get an error message, which reads: 'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.', when I tried to put `annotate` before the other plots. However, I managed to solve the problem by using `scale_x_discrete()` to specify to ggplot2 that I am using a discrete scale for the x axis.

```
ggplot(data = factor_output) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  coord_flip() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = c(0.3, -0.3, -0.3), ymax = c(Inf, -Inf, 0.3),
           xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
           alpha = 0.4, fill = c("LightGreen", "LightGreen", "Orange")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-0.75, -0.5, -0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = F.Difference, x = reorder(Action.Title, F.Difference), fill=Efficacy.Median), stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(Action.Title, F.Difference), y = Factor1, colour="DarkRed"), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(Action.Title, F.Difference), y = Factor2, colour="DarkBlue"), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Factor 1", "Factor 2"), values = c("DarkRed", "DarkBlue")) +
  labs(colour="Coefficient Value") +
  ggtitle("XXX") +
  xlab("XXX") +
  ylab("XXX") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.position = c(0, 1),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
        plot.title = element_text(colour = "DarkRed", size = 22, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ggplot adds layers on top of each other, so if I understand your question correctly, you can solve this by putting +annotate() before +geom_point() and +geom_bar(), like this:

```
ggplot(data = factor_output, aes(y=F.Difference, x=reorder(Action.Title, F.Difference), fill=Efficacy.Median)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  annotate("rect", ymin = c(0.3, -0.3, -0.3), ymax = c(Inf, -Inf, 0.3),
       xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
       alpha = 0.1, fill = c("green", "green", "orange")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(aes(y=Factor1, colour="DarkRed"), size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Factor2, colour="DarkBlue"), size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Factor 1", "Factor 2"), values = c("DarkRed", "DarkBlue")) +
  labs(colour="Coefficient Value") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "DarkGreen", size = 18),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title= element_text(size = 15),
    legend.text= element_text(size = 12),
    legend.position = c(0, 1),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
    plot.title = element_text(colour = "DarkRed", size = 22, hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this before I posted my thread, but I got the following message: 'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.'